# Django clean() method raises 'Bid' object has no attribute 'kwargs'

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

I'm trying to restrict a bidder that bids on certain project via a form from bidding neither less than the minimum budget that the project publisher has specifies neither greater than the maximum budget. After checking similar problems i found that overriding the clean method is the most suitable, but i'm facing " 'Bid' object has no attribute 'kwargs' " error

This is the clean method:

```
    def clean(self):
        if Project.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).budget_min >= self.bid_amount or self.bid_amount >= Project.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).budget_max:
            raise ValidationError('the bid amount should be between the minimum and maximum project budget')
```

This is my models.py

```
# projects/models.py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinLengthValidator, MinValueValidator
from upload_validator import FileTypeValidator
from .validators import user_directory_path, validate_file_size
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField


class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        'Choose a title for your project',
        max_length=255,
        validators=[
            MinLengthValidator(
                15, 'Title must be descriptive and greater than 15 characters')
        ]
    )
    body = models.TextField('Tell us more about your project',
                            max_length=3000,
                            validators=[
                                MinLengthValidator(
                                    10, 'Must be descriptive and greater than 10 characters')
                            ]
                            )
    upload_file = models.FileField(
        upload_to=user_directory_path,
        verbose_name="upload file:(Max file size: 2.5 MB)",
        validators=[
            validate_file_size,
            FileTypeValidator(
                allowed_types=[
                    'application/msword',
                    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                    'application/pdf',
                    'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
                    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
                    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                    'image/tiff',
                    'image/jpeg',
                    'image/png'
                ],
                allowed_extensions=['.doc', '.docx',
                                    '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.pdf', '.zip']
            )
        ],
        null=True, blank=True
    )

    POSSIBLE_SKILLS = (
        ('Bash Scripting', 'Bash Scripting'), ('CSS', 'CSS'), ('Django', 'Django'),
        ('HTML', 'HTML'), ('JavaScript', 'JavaScript'), ('React', 'React'),
        ('Linux', 'Linux'), ('MongoDB', 'MongoDB'), ('NoSQL', 'NoSQL'),
        ('Powershell', 'Powershell'), ('Python', 'Python'),
        ('Shell Script', 'Shell Script')
    )
    skills = MultiSelectField(choices=POSSIBLE_SKILLS, default='')
    PAYMENT_TYPE = (
        ('Fixed', 'Fixed'),
        ('Hourly', 'Hourly'),
    )
    payments = models.CharField(
        'How do you want to pay?',
        max_length=20, choices=PAYMENT_TYPE, default="Fixed")
    budget_min = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        'What is your estimated Minimum budget?',
        default=10, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100000)])
    budget_max = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        'What is your estimated Maximum budget? :',
        default=100, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100000)])
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # author is a FOREIGN KEY field in Project table, that refers to the PRIMARY KEY in CustomUser table
    # the on_delete method used to tell django when deleting the author delete he's projects
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    # Shows up in the admin list
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """[summary: where to go when a Project object is created. 
]

        Returns:
            [description: this method should appear to return a string that can be used to refer
            to the object over HTTP.]
        """
        return reverse('project_detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class Bid(models.Model):
    bid_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=10, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(1000000)]
    )
    delivery_in = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(10000)]
    )
    describe_your_proposal = models.TextField(
        max_length=144,
        validators=[
            MinLengthValidator(
                20, "bid must be descriptive and greater than 20 characters")
        ]
    )
    STATUS_TYPE = (
        ('Approved', 'Approved'),
        ('Closed', 'Closed'),
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        'How do you want to pay?',
        max_length=20, choices=STATUS_TYPE, default="Pending")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # project is a FOREIGN KEY field in Bid table, that refers to
    # the PRIMARY KEY in Project table using related name project.bids
    # in templates to access bids of the project
    # the on_delete method used to tell django when deleting the project delete it's bids
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='bids',
    )
    # author is a FOREIGN KEY field in Bid table, that refers to
    # the PRIMARY KEY in CustomUser table
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    #
    def clean(self):
        if Project.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).budget_min >= self.bid_amount or self.bid_amount >= Project.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).budget_max:
            raise ValidationError('the bid amount should be between the minimum and maximum project budget')

    # Shows up in the admin list
    def __str__(self):
        return self.describe_your_proposal

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """[summary: where to go when a Bid object is created.
    ]

        Returns:
            [description: this method should appear to return a string that can be used
            to refer to the object over HTTP.]
        """
        return reverse('bid_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Comment: Try changing `self.kwargs[‘pk’]` to `self.pk `. If that does not work what is the code you use to call clean and could you include the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

If the project referenced in the clean method is the `bid.project` object, then you can just call it directly.

```
def clean(self):
    if not self.project.budget_min <= self.bid_amount <= self.project.budget_max:
        raise ValidationError('The bid amount should be between the minimum and maximum project budget.')
```

I'd also recommend switching up the check if the bid is in between the min and max values, I think it is easier to read.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but this does not solve the problem instead it raises this problem.
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /projects/bid/3/new/
Bid has no project.